# Meteor & React with reactive styling

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, meteor

Being new to both Meteor and React, I'm going about this is a non-reactive way and I know it's incorrect, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what the proper way to do this might be.

1) logIn and logOut variables should be a function, I think, but I'm not clear on how to put a function in a render.

2) Meteor.logout(document.location.reload());, seems incorrect.

I feel like I could merge these two concepts into one.

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
    var navStyle = {
      backgroundColor: "#263238",
      paddingLeft: "10px"
    };
    var logIn = {
      display: (Meteor.userId() ? "none" : "block")
    };
    var logOut = {
      display: (Meteor.userId() ? "block" : "none")
    };
    return (
      <nav style={navStyle}>
        <div>
          <a href="/" className="brand-logo">ShortShape</a>
          <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" className="button-collapse"><i className="material-icons">menu</i></a>
          <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li style={logOut}><a href="javascript:Meteor.logout(document.location.reload());">Logout</a></li>
            <li style={logIn}><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
            <li style={logIn}><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stories">Stories</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul className="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li style={logOut}><a href="javascript:Meteor.logout(document.location.reload());">Logout</a></li>
            <li style={logIn}><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
            <li style={logIn}><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stories">Stories</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your component renders reactively, you need to wrap it in a reactive container. There are quite a lot reactive container out there, but I usually use [`createContainer`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data) which is the official container from Meteor team

```
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

class Header extends React.Component {
  logout() {
    Meteor.logout(() => {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  }
  render() {
    const user = this.props.user;

    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
    var navStyle = {
      backgroundColor: "#263238",
      paddingLeft: "10px"
    };
    var logIn = {
      display: (user ? "none" : "block")
    };
    var logOut = {
      display: (user ? "block" : "none")
    };
    return (
      <nav style={navStyle}>
        <div>
          <a href="/" className="brand-logo">ShortShape</a>
          <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" className="button-collapse"><i className="material-icons">menu</i></a>
          <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li style={logOut}>
              <a onClick={this.logout}>Logout</a>
            </li>
            <li style={logIn}><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
            <li style={logIn}><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stories">Stories</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul className="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li style={logOut}>
              <a onClick={this.logout}>Logout</a>
            </li>
            <li style={logIn}><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
            <li style={logIn}><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="/stories">Stories</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default createContainer(() => {
  // this function will run reactively
  return {
    user: Meteor.user(),
  };
}, Header);
```

Comment: So is the `window.location.reload(); superfluous? Should `Meteor.logout(() => {` effectively change the condition, or because it's a constant it's stuck without a reload?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. The function passed to `createContainer` will re-run when user is logged out. `window.location.reload()` is needed or not depends on your requirements, if you need to clear all in-memory data (`Session` for ex), `reload` is a good option

Comment: I think my question is, does the page need to be reloaded, or is there a better way to dynamically update the stylings?

Comment: Further, is document.location.href actually a good practice? Or is there a better way to route?